# Number of ones in generating matrix

Tags: coding-theory

I'm getting a hard time with the following question:

> Let $G$ be a generator matrix of an $(n,k,d)$ binary linear code, then $G$ has at least $kd$ ones on it.

The question is taken from [Essential Coding Theory](https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/atri/courses/coding-theory/book/chapters/chap1.pdf) (question 1.12).

I tried to use the linear dependency of columns of $G$ and the distance between them. I also tried to assume towards contradiction that $G$ contains at most $kd-1$ ones, but didn't get a contradiction.

Any hint will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: All the rows of $G$ are words of the code.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

In the generator matrix $G$ has $k$ rows because the binary code $C$ has papmeter $[n, k, d]$. In $G$ every row is a non zero codeword of $C$. Since $C$ is $[n, k, d]$ binary code, every non zero codeword has $\geq d$ ones. So total number of ones in $G$ is $\geq dk$.

Comment: Thank you. I already managed to prove it using Jyrki's hint.